# ASP.NET TextBox restricts input/output to around 500 characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm using a TextBox to insert a extensive line of text into SQL on which the field is currently of type nvarchar limited to 3000.

The TextBox will show all that I've written yet once I press to submit it will send to DB a shorter/cut version.

Textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="SummaryTextBox" CssClass="SummaryTextBox" runat="server" EnableTheming="True" TextMode="MultiLine" MaxLength="3000"></asp:TextBox>
```

Click event:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Leo\\Desktop\\PAP\\App_Data\\AnimationFront.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["animeid"]);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "Anime_SP";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@acao", "UPDATES");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_Anime", id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Summary", SummaryTextBox.Text);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    Response.Redirect("AnimePage.aspx?animeid=" + id);

}
```

Stored Procedure:

```
IF @acao = 'UPDATES'
  BEGIN
        UPDATE Anime
        SET Summary = @Summary
        WHERE Id_Anime = @Id_Anime
  END
```

Comment: Can you show us your code

Comment: What is the problem? You can insert 500 characters but you want 3000? Have you checked `MaxLength`? Is it a multiline `TextBox`? Any codebehind which might shorten the text before inserting it?

Comment: You could use something like https://ace.c9.io/ to do code editing in :)

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="SummaryTextBox" CssClass="SummaryTextBox" runat="server" EnableTheming="True" TextMode="MultiLine" MaxLength="3000"></asp:TextBox>

This is the current code of the TextBox (3000 was an absurd number I used to check if indeed the string was within the size limit).

Comment: @CallumLinington why should he tough, and that really has nothing to do with the question, does it?

Comment: Try a `textarea` maybe?

Comment: @MrSanchez He wants to edit SQL in a text box.... sounds like he wants edit some code, so why not use a code editor - no it doesn't answer his question (but that is why it is a comment) - it is just a suggestion

Comment: @CallumLinington He doesn't want to edit SQL in a textBox, he is adding a massive string from a textbox, that string is just plain text, the problem he is having is that the string is getting concatenated.

Comment: @Leo post the string in here as well btw.

Comment: A couple of things. I don't believe the MaxLength constraint on asp:TextBox has any effect when set as MultiLine (i.e. textarea). I suspect the concatenation is occuring SQL Server side. Does your stored procedure define a size for the @Summary parameter?

Comment: Ah, I see you literally just worked this out yourself!!

Comment: Yes the problem was the size on @Summary found out a couple minutes ago also will I was searching for a way to fix my problem I found out that maxlength doesn't really work but in my case I wasn't really trying to limit my input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to change the parameter from the Post Procedure from NVARCHAR(500) to NVARCHAR(3000) when I made the change.

```
@acao NVARCHAR(10)
  ,@Id_Anime INT = NULL
  ,@Title NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
  ,@Genre NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
  ,@Episodes INT = NULL
  ,@Studios NVARCHAR (100) = NULL
  ,@Prequels NVARCHAR (100) = NULL
  ,@Sequels NVARCHAR (100) = NULL
  ,@Cover NVARCHAR (100) = NULL
  ,@Summary NVARCHAR (500) = NULL
```

Comment: Thanks anyway guys sry for my clumsiness.